# Dropbox - App folder deleted - getting NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted error - iOS

Tags: ios, dropbox

I am using Core API for integrating dropbox with an iOS app. I am able to authenticate an account, and successfully upload files.

But say after authentication, user deletes the app folder from the dropbox account, or uninstalls the app through dropbox settings.

After that if I try to upload a file, the whole file gets uploaded (progress reaches from 0 to 1) and then I receive an error with error code `-1021` which corresponds to `NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted`, and nor error code `401` according to Standard API errors in https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api.
The issue is that this is happening on devices with iOS 6, even the account is not unlinked by itself.
I have a device with iOS 5, which gets an error code of `401` (but that too after the whole file has been uploaded), which is authentication error (error code 401) as explained in core api docs. And the account gets unlinked by itself.

**Update:** This bug has been solved in the latest dropbox core api Build.

Comment: I asked the same question on dropbox forums. They say that there is some problem with the framework itself, and this issue comes only when uploading files. So they suggest loading metadata just after login to confirm whether or not authentication has been provided.

Comment: on a sidenote, I used the words "Google Drive" and "Android" inside the app. Will my app be rejected now? I have submitted it already

Comment: No ideas at all. We'll wait and watch. Let me know what happens :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLErrorDomain error -1021](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117275/nsurlerrordomain-error-1021)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will immediately request the users Dropbox account information (if they are currently linked) when your app is launched.  If the user deletes the apps folder, or revokes access to your app from Dropbox.com, then the user will be immediately unlinked when your app is launched.  I think this is good practice regardless of if the SDK has a bug that fails to return 401 when uploading a file.

**Add this to your app delegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`method where you initialize Dropbox**

```
DBSession* dbSession = [[[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:DROPBOX_KEY appSecret:DROPBOX_SECRET root:kDBRootAppFolder] autorelease];
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    DBRestClient* dbRestClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    [dbRestClient setDelegate:self];
    [dbRestClient loadAccountInfo];
}
```

**Then add the following method to your app delegate**

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadAccountInfoFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
    if (error.code == 401) {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
    }
}
```

Comment: That can be done, but it is happening only once when the app starts. What if after app starts, that app un-linked? Then again wrong error code will be sent.. We should do such thing before every upload, I don't see the point of doing it just once. The point is to make some query that confirms that the account has not been unlinked.

Comment: So, @neeraj In my app as a temporary solution (until the SDK is updated), if i get an error uploading a file i treat it as the account is unlinked.  Another solution is if an error is returned when uploading a file, immediately request the users account information to check if its unlinked.  If you get back a 401 then the person is no longer linked, if you get back the users information then the upload failed for some other reason, and prompt the user to try again.

Comment: yeah that can be done. Consider -1021 error code as no authorization error code. Or, you can use this https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=98962#post-538908 .