# NSURLErrorDomain error -1021

Tags: ios, iphone, dropbox, nsurl, nsurlerrordomain

I'm developing an app were I integrated dropbox. Login is done properly also I'm able to create folder in dropBox. But when I try to load file I'm getting error

Following error I'm getting

```
error making request to /1/files_put/dropbox/Info.plist - Error
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "The operation couldn’t be
completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1021.)" UserInfo=0x6859bc0
{destinationPath=/Info.plist,
sourcePath=/Users/bcod/Library/Application Support/iPhone
Simulator/5.0/Applications/0E1EE43C-8F6B-40FA-8696-D3992DA2DCE5/DBRoulette.app/Info.plist}
```

I'm not getting this error when I'm creating folder.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with iOS 5.0 on iPhone, but the iPhone 6.1 simulator worked without creating error messages.

I took a look into the DropboxSDK / DBRestClient.m, especially the last lines of uploadFile:toPath:fromPath:params and implemented a categorie 'ExBody' on DBRequest to add the connection:needNewBodyStream method:

```
#import "DBRequest+ExBody.h"

@implementation DBRequest (ExBody)

#pragma mark NSURLConnection delegate methods

- (NSInputStream *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *)req {

    NSString * sourcePath = [userInfo objectForKey:@"sourcePath"];
    NSLog(@"%@ needs newBodyStream!", sourcePath);
    return [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:sourcePath];
}

@end
```

This worked for me. The method is called on iOS5, not on iOS6!

Comment: Absolutely life saver. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks! I've reported the problem to Dropbox. They plan to include the fix in the next version.

Comment: Hi @TomThumb - I replicated these two files in my project. Should I #import the .h file somewhere?

Comment: There's no need to import (or actually create) the .h file. Just link the .m file.

Comment: The 1.3.5 SDK includes this fix.

Answer (score 4):

Error -1021 is a `NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted` error.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) you're missing a delegate method:

> **NSURLErrorRequestBodyStreamExhausted**
>   Returned when a body stream is
>   needed but the client does not provide one. This impacts clients on
>   iOS that send a POST request using a body stream but do not implement
>   the NSURLConnection delegate method connection:needNewBodyStream.
>   Available in OS X v10.7 and later.

Comment: I tried calling delegate DBNetworkRequestDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate but still getting same error

Comment: Did you add the `connection:needNewBodyStream` method?

Comment: how should I implement that method

Comment: Read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This error is coming from within the Dropbox SDK, so probably impossible for @user2185354 to implement. That is, the Dropbox SDK library might need to implement this, but he has no access to the `NSURLConnection`.